# how to make dynamic namespace or scopes route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to make admin route with namespace but it doest trigger to the route

I run `rails g controller admin`

it created the file `app/controllers/admin_controller.rb` , `app/views/admin/index.html.haml`

my namespace look like this

```
namespace :admin do
   controller :admin do
     get '/', :index
   end
end
```

it doesn't trigger to `localhost:3000/admin` it said not found for that route
any idea ??

Comment: How exactly do you want your routes to look like? Can you give an example? What do you try to achieve with the `controller :admin do` block? I have never seen such a block before and cannot find it in the docs.

Comment: i want to create `localhost:3000/admin` with namespace, what example u mean?

Comment: What do you mean by _with namespace_? `/admin` doesn't look like a namespace, it looks like a singular resource. When you just want to route `/admin` to the `AdminsController#index` then `get '/admin', to: 'admin#index'`. But keep in mind that singular controller name is not following Rails conventions. Using `resource :admin` that your route to `AdminsController#show` might be better. Did you have a look at: [the Rails Guide about Routing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)?

Comment: i got it, so if i use namespace :admin, i should have folder `app/controllers/admin/admin_controller.rb` ? right ? and how to use views for that namespace ? can u give example on answer below

Comment: @spickerman 'controller :admin do' is equivalent to 'scope controller: :admin'. But combined with namespace it will route to Admin::AdminController...

Comment: can u answer my question on below, i do love to get the right answer and example so i will solve this question

Comment: @spickermann https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`namespace` not only adds a path prefix but it also adds a module nesting to the expected controller. For example:

```
namespace :blog do
  resources :posts
end
```

Will create the route `/blog/posts => Blog::PostsController#index`.

In your example Rails expects the controller to be defined as:

```
# app/controllers/admin/admin_controller.rb
module Admin
  class AdminController
    # GET /admin
    def index
    end
  end
end
```

If you just want to add a path prefix or other options to the routes without module nesting use `scope` instead:

```
scope :admin, controller: :admin do
  get '/', action: :index
end
```

This will route `/admin` to `AdminController#index`

But if this just a one off route you could just write:

```
get :admin, to: 'admin#index'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller path needs to be in the `admin` namespace.

So the filename for the admin controller needs to be `app/controllers/admin/admin_controller.rb`.

Comment: just did, but doesn't work, maybe wrong on namespace codes ??

Comment: Try changing the routes to read `get "/",  to: "admin#index"` and get rid of the do block.

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing the routes file?

Comment: The controller would also have to be in a module named Admin.

Comment: Yep totally forgot that part.